# BCNF decomposition --- Am I doing this wrong?

Tags: database, database-normalization, bcnf

I am working on lossless-join decomposition on the relation R(A,B,C,D,E).

The relation has functional dependencies: {A->BC,B->D,CD->E,E->A}

(1) I think candidate keys are {A} and {E}

(2) And BCNF violations are {B->D} and {CD->E}, because {B} and {CD} are not candidate keys

(3) But I don't know how to decompose it and which dependencies are not preserved. I guess it would be like...

=> R1={A,B,C,E}, R2={B,D} and lose FDs: {CD->E}

But both {A} and {E} are candidate keys, so does it need to be separated like below?

=> R1{A,B,C}, R2{B,D}, R3{B,C,E} and lose FDs: {CD->E}

I want to ask which one is correct

Comment: Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & show your work & justification for what you think is correct & dubious. There are algorithms to put into NFs, separate from definitions--what were you told to use? "A bit wierd" means nothing, please explain how there is a problem following what you are supposed to do. If you don't know what you are supposed to do, find out & tell us. PS "Its dependencies" means nothing--you mean, that is a cover for the non-trivial FDs that hold in it.

Comment: thank you, I will correct it!

Comment: You edited after your comment. Ok, you replaced 'wierd', good. But I can't make sense of your new text. Also, see the rest of my comment. Eg: Per the answer below (1) is wrong. But you don't show your work. So really you are expecting us to 1. do that work when you could just show it & we could check it & 2. tell you what you did wrong when you didn't show us what you did. This is why you should show your work. *Just like all through the rest of your school life.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) is wrong, since also `BC` and `CD` are candidate keys (for instance, since `CD → E` and `E` is a candidate key, it is easy to see that also `CD` must be a candidate key). Another way of checking this is computing `CD+`:

```
CD+ = CD
CD+ = CDE (by using CD -> E)
CD+ = CDEA (by using E -> A)
CD+ = CDEAB (by using A -> BC)
```

CD+ is equal to all the attributes of the relation and this means that it is a superkey. Moreover, since you cannot remove any attribute from with without losing the property of determining all the attributes of the relation, this means it is a candidate key.

So `B → D` is the only dependency that violates the BCNF, and for this reason you can decompose `R` in `R1(BD)` with candidate key `B` and `R2(ABCE)` with candidate keys  `A`, `BC`, and `E`. Both relations are in BCNF, so no further decomposition is necessary.

Because of this decomposition, it is true that the dependency `CD → E` is lost.

Comment: Thank you. I know candidate key can be composite, but since {A} and {E} have single attribute, doesn't it mean {CD} is not a candidate key?
(I remember candidate key has to be  "minimal attribute set" )

Comment: A candidate key is “minimal” in the sense that you cannot remove any attribute from it (if it is a multi-attribute candidate key) without losing the property of being candidate key. You can check that a set of attributes like CD is a candidate key by computing its closure (i.e. CD+)

Comment: I want to take you as the useful answer, but the system won't let a user has less 15 reputation to do that. I am sorry about this, though, the system will record it after I get 15 reputation!